# Auto light and dark mode for assets SwiftUI?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

Similar to how I can pick a color for light and dark mode in my app's assets on Xcode, is there any way I can pick an image to be used in light and dark mode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is! If you go to your `assets` in XCode and select your image, in the inspector sidebar, you can find a drop down menu `Appearance` which will give you the ability to input and display images based on the device's appearance preference.

[image: On the right side bar, you can see the Appearances dropdown]